# SPA Authentication AngularJS -> PassportJS -> MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am trying for days to setup Passport on SPA page. On Client Side I am using AngularJS $http and generally it's working.

```
angular.module('Factory', []).factory('MainFactory', ['$http',function($http) {
    return {
        RegisterNewAccount : function(AccountInformation) {
            return $http.post('/api/PageSignup', AccountInformation);
        }
    }
}]);
angular.module('Controllers', [])
.controller('MainPage', ['$scope','MainFactory', function($scope, MainFactory) {
    $scope.Signup = function(){
        var account = {
            email: $scope.RegisterEmail,
            password: $scope.RegisterPassword
        };
        MainFactory.RegisterNewAccount(account)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

My problem is on server side code, i am new to passport and still cant figure it out how to make it work without redirect thing. My passport setup is below:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy= require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    if (email) email = email.toLowerCase();
    process.nextTick(function() {
        if (!req.user) {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                if (user) return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is already taken.' });
                else {
                    var newUser            = new User();
                    newUser.local.email    = email;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) return done(err);
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else if ( !req.user.local.email ) {
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) return done(err);       
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is already taken.'});
                } else {
                    var user = req.user;
                    user.local.email = email;
                    user.local.password = user.generateHash(password);
                    user.save(function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);

                        return done(null,user);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return done(null, req.user);
        }
    });
}));
var app      = express();
app.post('/api/PageSignup', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {
      return res.send(info.message);
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      return res.send(user);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

If there are clear example on SPA Authentication with passport please show me.
Overwise can you show me where I am mistaking in my server side code?

Comment: What is your unexpected point with your code?

Comment: I have figure it out how to do authentication without redirect, perhaps i should delete this post or answer it my self. The problem was in Route.